# How to add uniqueness validation for one model depending on another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to validate a "House Name" for each "User" . 
if i just put
              validates :House_name , uniqueness: true
then it will check for all housenames. I want to validate only based on my current user. i.e, one user cannot have multiple house names in same name but other users can have the same house name .

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while back. There are two solutions depending on how you have it setup.

1. In your `user.rb` you can add a custom method like so (assuming User has an array called `house_names`:

`validate :house_name_is_unique`

```
def house_name_is_unique
        unless (house_names.length == houses.uniq.length)
            errors.add(:house_names, :blank, message: "name taken")
        end
end
```

The above code will check the array of house names, and the `uniq` method filters out duplicates so if they are the same length, there were no duplicates so do nothing, otherwise complain.

2. Use `scope` (untested) You can add the following to your `house.rb` class

`validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id,  message: "no duplicate house name" }`

You can read more about scope here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `user` model has `has_many: houses` association, you can try this:

```
validate :house_uniqueness

def house_uniqueness
  errors.add(:base, "House name has been taken") if House.exists?(user: self, name: 
  self.house_name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class User
  has_many :houses
end

class House
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :user_id
end
```

[API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)